# Animation using NSTimer and the position of the UIImageView frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation

Hi and thanks in advance for any help and contribution :)

I am currently working on a personal project(some sort of a mmorpg) AND I'am stuck at the walking animation. 
Until now I have made the map and implemented the A* pathfinder that returns a path array in C style. 
What I am trying to do is to change the background image of an UIImageFrame and de/increment its x and y position  depending on the values stored in an array.
The ideea was to change the background image and de/increase X or Y by 2px using an NSTimer, every 0,1s.
The NStimer will call the animation function 32 times before it is invalidated.

And here is the code for the 4 possible directions( N/S/W/E):

In the .h file:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    int xMyCharacterFrame;
    int yMyCharacterFrame;
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        int counterInMilisecondsForAnimation;
        UIImageView *myCharacterFrame ;
    }
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timerForSouthMoving;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timerForNorthMoving;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timerForEstMoving;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timerForWestMoving;


    -(void)southAnimation;
    -(void)northAnimation;
    -(void)estAnimation;
    -(void)westAnimation;
    @end
```

In the .m file:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        myCharacterFrame = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        myCharacterFrame.frame = CGRectMake(xMyCharacterFrame, yMyCharacterFrame, 100, 100);
        myCharacterFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s0.png"];
    }
```

When the game is started the xMyCharacterFrame are laoded form NSUserDefaults. ANd the recalculated depending on the user tap. The game is a 2d map based, with tiles of 64*64 px.
        -(void)findPathForStart:(int)start andFinish:(int)stop{
//after the path is find using the self implemented A* pathfinder, the walking animation should use 
the resulted path find array, that is two dimensional, first position Y and on the second the X.
On the fist 2d array of the path array I store the finish position, so in order to animate I need to read it in reverse.

```
     int xWayOfMoving;
     int yWayOfMoving;

    for (int possitionInThePathArray = sizeOfPathArray - 1; possitionInThePathArray >= 0; possitionInThePathArray--) {

            xWayOfMoving= pathArray[possitionInThePathArray-1][1] - pathArray[possitionInThePathArray][1];

            yWayOfMoving= pathArray[possitionInThePathArray-1][0] - pathArray[possitionInThePathArray][0];

     if (xWayOfMoving== 0 && yWayOfMoving== 1) {
   //animate north

        [timerForSouthMoving invalidate];
        timerForSouthMoving = nil;
        counterInMilisecondsForAnimation= 0;
            timerPentruAnimatieDeplasare = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                                 target: self
                                               selector:@selector(northAnimation)
                                               userInfo: nil
                                                repeats:YES];


    }else if (xWayOfMoving== 0 && yWayOfMoving== -1){
  //animate south
        [timerForNorthMoving invalidate];
        timerForNorthMoving= nil;
        counterInMilisecondsForAnimation= 0;
            timerForNorthMoving= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                                 target: self
                                               selector:@selector(northAnimation)
                                               userInfo: nil
                                                repeats:YES];


    }else if (xWayOfMoving== 1 && yWayOfMoving== 0){
   // animate west
        [timerForWestMovinginvalidate];
        timerForWestMoving= nil;
        counterInMilisecondsForAnimation= 0;

            timerForWestMoving = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                                 target: self
                                               selector:@selector(northAnimation)
                                               userInfo: nil
                                                repeats:YES];


    }else if (xWayOfMoving== -1 && yWayOfMoving == 0){
   //animate est
        [timerForEstMoving invalidate];
        timerForEstMoving = nil;
        counterInMilisecondsForAnimation= 0;
            timerForEstMoving = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                                 target: self
                                               selector:@selector(northAnimation)
                                               userInfo: nil
                                                repeats:YES]; 
    }  
}
}
```

One of the 4 functions for the walking animation:

-(void)northAnimation{

```
if (counterInMilisecondsForAnimation< 33) {
    if (counterCharacterImageSouth == 11) {
        counterCharacterImageSouth = 0;}

myCharacterFrame.frame = CGRectMake(xMyCharacterFrame, yMyCharacterFrame, 100, 100);
myCharacterFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"scientist_s%d.png", counterCharacterImageSouth]];

yMyCharacterFrame = yMyCharacterFrame - 2;
        counterCharacterImageSouth++;

    counterInMilisecondsForAnimation++;
   }
   else{
     [timerForSouthMoving invalidate];
   } 
  }
```

Comment: I would seriously look at Cocos2d as a framework for your game.

Comment: This might be  a useful read:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html  Animation with a timer will be verbose and jumpy.  Also, do you add the image view myCharacterFrame as a subview someplace?  It looks like you build it in viewDidLoad and then forget about it.

Comment: Yes I add it to a UIScrollView. I was thinking that the problem it may be due to the for loop and the way  it iterates over the path array and then enters the if else if... I say so because when I tap on the screen it animates only for 64px, that means it only loops once through the for loop which it's wrong..

Comment: You shouldn't use a NSTimer for any animations. Use CADisplayLink. CADisplayLink is more precise since it is fired around the refresh rate of the display (60fps). I think that change will solve some of your issues.